# How to analyse seasonal variation in stroke onset?

Tags: time-series

I am dealing with the topic of seasonal variation and stroke. I would like to do  time series analysis.For time variable I have stroke onset month and all the other variables are categorical in nature. How should I analyze these data?

Comment: can you add an example of your data?

Answer (score 1):

One way to take into account the seasonal effect is to add dummies for 11 months (assume Jan as the base to avoid dummy variable trap). You can include other variables as usual. If you also want to take into account heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation , you can use Newey West HAC standard error.